# get js file query param from inside it

Tags: javascript

I load this file with some query param like this:
`src='somefile.js?userId=123'`

I wrote the below function in 'somefile.js' file that reads the 'userId' query param
but I feel this is not the best approach. Frankly, its quite ugly. **Is there a better way**?

```
function getId(){
   var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'), script;
   for(var i in scripts){
        if( scripts.hasOwnProperty(i) && scripts[i].src.indexOf('somefile.js') != -1 )
            var script = scripts[i];
   }

    var s = (script.getAttribute.length !== undefined) ? 
        script.getAttribute('src') : 
        script.getAttribute('src', 2);

   return getQueryParams('userId',s);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// extracts the params from the currently running (external) script
var getScriptQp = (function(){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var this_script_tag = scripts[scripts.length - 1]; //script tag of this file

    if( typeof this_script_tag != undefined && this_script_tag.src )
        var s = this_script_tag.src;
    else{
        return this.customer;
    }
    return s;
})();

// gets the Query Params of a givver query string
function getQueryParam(name, query){
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(query);
    if (results == null)
        return "";
    else
        return results[1];
}

getQueryParam( 'param',getScriptQp );
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the `script` elements in the `head` section is the way to go. There's an [article](http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html) with sample code. This approach seems fragile as the name of the script is hardcoded and if it is renamed it might break.

Comment: my script is hosted on a server and isn't intended to work localy so the name of it isn't quite an issue in the case

Comment: the article's method is basically like what I used to do: 'var myScript = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ]', but this failed for me in one test, so I changed it to look the script with indexOf...

Comment: and also another thing, scripts can be anywhere, not just in the <head> section of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative ways are:

1. Just set a JS variable with that value. E.g. `<script>var userId = 123;</script>`.
2. Put the value in a hidden (input) element somewhere in the HTML DOM and access it the usual way.

That said, keep in mind that JS code runs at the client side and is fully controllable by the client. You should for instance really not let the JS do some user-specific logic which is *dependent* on the userId. In such case, rather keep the userId in session in the server side and make use of ajax to get the result.

Comment: I used to use these alternative ways but they just feel dirty to me

Comment: this is for my js plugin file, which will be hosted on many sites, not just mine

Comment: Well, I think you have to be more pragmatic than puristic.

Comment: I've just seen a bunch of web widgets and services use this technique so I thought its a nice to solve everything in one js line

Comment: Wrap it in a function which you hide far away :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm pretty sure that if you pass your params via the URL to your script it essentially means that the client will never cache your JS file, since everytime it appears as a different URL and will be re-downloaded.